# ¿Por qué al realizar una petición ajax no llega a complete:function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estoy teniendo un caso en el cual al realizar una petición y tener el resultado correcto no llega al apartado de complete: function (), lo cual me bloquearia mi pantalla para continuar con el funcionamiento normal

Este es mi código:

````
        async: false,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(datosActivacion),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.estatus === "success") {
                $("#mdlCodigoConfirmacion").modal("toggle");
            } else if (result.estatus === "errorS") {
                var resE = JSON.parse(result.response);
                if (resE.message === "Límite de intentos alcanzado.") {
                    mostarModalSoloAceptar(resE.message + ". Espere 15 minutos para un nuevo intento de activacion");
                } else {
                    mostarModalSoloAceptar(resE.message);
                }
            }
            else {
                mostarModalSoloAceptar(result.response);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            waitingDialog.hide();
            mostarModalSoloAceptar("Error al intentar conectar al servidor");
        },
        complete: function () {
            waitingDialog.hide();
        }
    });```
````

Comment: Hola MrVergil, ¿qué estado está retornando el servidor?
Recuerda las diferencias entre success y complete según la documentación de [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Se llama a success() cuando el servidor devuelve un código de estado 200, se llama al complete() siempre que se completa la solicitud.